# How an exported require statement can be translated using import/export ES6 notation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I've the following statement:

```
exports.users = require("./users.js");
```

How can I convert that in a statement using the import/export notation defined in EcmaScript6?

Comment: I've tried different approaches but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please show those approaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
export { default as users } from './users';
//       ^^^^^^^ or whatever the module exports
```